# jquery multiple label slider filter table on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**jsfiddle link** : http://jsfiddle.net/u9gpsb8h/20/
i want to filter table based on jquery label slider .

something like query show tr where td1

i have two slider 1 and 2, now i want to filter table based on slider value slider 1 represents filter a and slider 2 represents filter b.

Problem is that my code works fine when for current label only

below is my js code

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider1" ).slider({
    value: 20,
    min:0,
    max:20,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#s1').html(jQuery('#slider1').slider('value'));
    // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the sliders        
    var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
           //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW

           if (j == 0) {             // if first column
               if ($(col).html() <= jQuery('#slider1').slider('value')) {
                   // if in interval
                   $(row).show();
               } else {
                   $(row).hide();
               }
           }
       }  
    }          
  }
  });
 $( "#slider2" ).slider({
    value: 20,
    min:0,
    max:20,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#s2').html(jQuery('#slider2').slider('value'));
    // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the sliders        
    var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
           //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW

           if (j == 1) {             // if first column
               if ($(col).html() <= jQuery('#slider2').slider('value')) {
                   // if in interval
                   $(row).show();
               } else {
                   $(row).hide();
               }
           }
       }  
        }          
      }
      });
  });
```

how can i sort table based on slider value i am newbie pls guide me to do this

Comment: Are you trying to sort the columns per increment? More correct sorting per each increment? Don't understand the question.

Comment: yeah sorting as soon as slide is done

Comment: so why use a slider, wouldn't a button work as well, why would you need a slider if the sorting is going to happen only once?

Comment: not once per increment, i want sort

Answer (score 0):

To get the filters to work together and not compete with each other, you will want to use a specific show/hide indicator for each slider, rather than .show() and .hide(), as it is, each one will overwrite the other.

So `Slider A` will filter results, and `Slider B` will further filter those results, rather than reset.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.slider1Hide{
    display:none;
}
.slider2Hide {
    display:none;
}
```

And for the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider1").slider({
        value: 20,
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#s1').html(jQuery('#slider1').slider('value'));
            // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the sliders        
            var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
            for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW

                    if (j === 0) { // if first column
                        if ($(col).html() <= ui.value) {
                            // if in interval
                            $(row).removeClass('slider1Hide');
                        } else {
                            $(row).addClass('slider1Hide');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $("#slider2").slider({
        value: 20,
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#s2').html(jQuery('#slider2').slider('value'));
            // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the sliders        
            var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
            for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW

                    if (j == 1) { // if first column
                        if ($(col).html() <= ui.value) {
                            // if in interval
                            $(row).removeClass('slider2Hide');
                        } else {
                            $(row).addClass('slider2Hide');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also as a side note, you can get the value of the slider from the ui in the slide callback by using `ui.value` rather than `jQuery('#slider1').slider('value')`