# javascript - Slider filtering table numeric column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, zurb-foundation

I am trying to add a slider on my page which is filtering a specific numeric column,of a specific  class of a specific class table.

I have tried to correct and make modifications of many existing [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841464/jquery-slider-range-apply-range-as-a-filter-on-table-rows),[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085129/jquery-multiple-label-slider-filter-table-on-change) ... without success.

I use Zurb-Foundation [slider](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html). Slider works for now, but it is not linked with anything of my page(not useful at all). Here is the HTML for the slider ;

```
<div class="large-9 columns">
   <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="0.5" data-end="1" data-step="0.05" id="slider-filter">
    <span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput1"></span>
    <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="small-3 columns">
<input type="number" id="slider-number">
</div>
```

According to the Foundation doc and examples above, here is my JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $("#slider-filter").slider({
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the sliders
            console.log("Slider is moving");
        }
    })
})
```

})

I am failing already at this part, of detecting my slider movement... I also tried according to the doc this line(`var elem = new Foundation.Slider(element, options);`) in order to use within the .slide()... no success.

Table example :

```
<table id="Table-to-filter">
 <tr>
   <td>First Column</td>
   <td>Second Column</td>
   <td>Third Column</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="Prt">
   <td>XXXX</td>
   <td>23</td>
   <td>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="Chi-to-filter">
   <td>XXXX</td>
   <td>51</td>
   <td>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="Chi-to-filter">
   <td>XXXX</td>
   <td>77</td>
   <td>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="Prt">
   <td>XXXX</td>
   <td>215</td>
   <td>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="Chi-to-filter">
   <td>XXXX</td>
   <td>450</td>
   <td>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="Chi-to-filter">
   <td>XXXX</td>
   <td>450</td>
   <td>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
```

Any detailed help would be more than appreciated to solve this problem using Foundation slider.

Thank you.

***After Nowres Rafed's response :***

[FILTERING OF BIGDATA TABLE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pmqoeb)

After many tries, here is what I have been able to do. I have explications and questions about my code. 
As you can see, my table is organised with this structure, an expandable parent row that gives many child rows if you click on arrow icon. I would like to use the slider to filter the "Score" column of both parent and child rows. My score is stored on a "accordion menu", not on a simple `<td>`.

I was wondering is there a better way to filter only the *Score column* ? I used the row.cells indice, does it change the speed to do it with the row.cells name (i.e "Score") ? Do you think I used the correct way to acces to my score value, using : `$(colx.getElementsByClassName("accordion-title")).html();`

Moreover, I divided the filtering of parent and child rows on two different loops, is it possible to improve this part ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you create a failing example, at least? That will be much easier and simpler to correct than us creating the example for you.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did not think about it. With the @Nowres Rafed's answer, it should work, I am trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the plugin in the wrong way, there is no jQuery plugin called slider in your code.

Here is a working example for your case:

```
$(function() {
    var $filter = $('.slider');

    $filter.foundation();
    $filter.on('moved.zf.slider', function() {
      var slideValue = $('#sliderOutput1').val();

      // Do your filtering here
      console.log(slideValue);
    });
});
```

Live: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbYZgO

Just add your columns filtering code and it's done.

**edited:**
I think you can make it simpler: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qvjqyo

add `score-value` class on each `accordion-title`, you can extend the exemple if you wish to distinguish between child and parent rows...

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I am still trying since your post to do it with my "more complex" table case. Then , I will edit my post and would you like to have your opinion on how I can improve my JS code.

Comment: I edited my initial post, can you have a look my code, I am not sure I used the best filtering way. Thank you, @Nowres Rafed.

Comment: Thank you for your edit comment, and for your help. It works as I want.